# UI freezes when using Async-await

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have got this function which freezes the UI:

```
Public Sub ValidateUrlContentAsync(externalApplyURL As String)

    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment()

    Dim result = Threading.Tasks.Task.
        Run( _
            Async Function()
                Return Await ValidateLinks.ValidateUrlContentAsync(externalApplyURL)
            End Function).
        ContinueWith(
            Sub(t)
                Try
                    If t.IsFaulted Then
                        Throw t.Exception
                    End If

                    If t.Result.Error IsNot Nothing Then
                        ErrorHandler.Log.Warn(
                            String.Format("ValidationError: {0}, Exception: {1}", externalApplyURL, t.Result.Error))
                    End If

                    AsyncManager.Parameters("validationResult") = t.Result.ResultValue.ToString()

                Finally
                    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement()
                End Try

            End Sub)

End Sub

 Public Function ValidateUrlContentCompleted(validationResult As String) As ActionResult

    Return Json(validationResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

End Function
```

I thought that `task.run` solves this issue because it creates a new thread separated from the UI thread, What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that stands out to me is the use of *three* separate asynchronous code patterns (`Await`, `ContinueWith`, and `AsyncManager`) instead of just using `Await`.

The other major thing is that you're returning an `ActionResult` - indicating this is an ASP.NET application - and yet talking about a "UI thread". There **is no** UI thread on ASP.NET.

Thus, I reinterpret "freezes the UI" as "does not return a result until the handler is complete", which is exactly how ASP.NET is *supposed* to work.

So, first, remove all the unnecessary `AsyncManager`, `ContinueWith`, and `Task.Run` code, which really simplifies the method:

```
Public Function ValidateUrlContent(externalApplyURL As String) As Task(Of ActionResult)
  Dim result = Await ValidateLinks.ValidateUrlContentAsync(externalApplyURL)
  If result.Error IsNot Nothing Then
    ErrorHandler.Log.Warn(String.Format("ValidationError: {0}, Exception: {1}", externalApplyURL, result.Error))
  End If
  Return Json(result.ResultValue.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

Next, solve the "freezing the UI" problem. The proper place to solve this problem is *in the UI*, not on the server (ASP.NET) side. The way to prevent the UI from freezing is to *call* the server in an asynchronous way. If you UI is a .NET application, you can use `Await` with `HttpClient` to call it asynchronously.

Comment: Amazing psychic diagnosis. +1 just for that. Let's see if it turns out to be true.

Comment: @OffirPe'er: I have an [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that may help, with good followup resources at the end. Regarding the `async:true` AJAX call, that's the JavaScript equivalent of "calling the server in an asynchronous way".

Answer (score 0):

You must Await the call to ValidateUrlContentAsnc. Turn it into a Function and return  Task.

Comment: That doesn't explain blocking.

Comment: @usr you're right. It must be `Increment()` that is blocking

Comment: I think there is something that's blocking and that is not visible in the code posted. This is not unusual for await questions. Often, users of await do not even know enough about it to post the relevant code.